# Angular-UI Bootstrap's typeahead ng-model doens't work as expected when placed inside tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm using [angular-ui typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#typeahead) plugin as following:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
```

when I place it inside [tabs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) the following watch expressing stopping to work:

```
$scope.$watch('selected', function(){
    console.log($scope.selected);
  });
```

Plunkr with example of my issue is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/65QrdX5DDA9YKenbEUbJ?p=preview

I don't think it's a bug but suspect that `<uib-tabset>` creates its own scope, but I haven't idea how to solve this issue.

**UPDATE1**:  I've solved this issue by using `$parent` scope as following:

`ng-model="$parent.$parent.selected"`

see updated plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/65QrdX5DDA9YKenbEUbJ?p=preview

But it looks for me terrible workaround, is it right to solve this issue in a way I've solved it and if not, what is right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A future proof design is always to use the **.property** in ng-model binding. Like what @Stanelyxu2005 and yourself have already figured out, an isolate scope is being created. By creating a scope variable like this

**JS**

```
$scope.selected = {city:"" };
$scope.$watch('selected.city', function(){
console.log($scope.selected.city);
});
```

**Markup**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected.city" uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
```

will ensure that the prototype chain remains true and is never broken. This will be a better way than using the ugly $parent.$parent workaround. See a link [here](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot) explaining why using the dot is good practice.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. `$parent` is indeed ugly :-(

Answer (score 3):

This is a common pitfall of angular user.

The `<input>` in your case actually creates an isolated scope. You want to access a shared variable`ng-model=your_var`, but it is actually a private variable in `<input>`'s scope. If a directive contains `<ng-swtich>`, it will also create an isolated scope.

Luckily you have found the solution already. Yes, you'd use `$parent.your_var` (maybe in some case `$parent.$parent`) to setup a correct data binding.

BTW: You might need to install an angular browser extension to explore the angular  scope hierarchy.